# Unit test with Chai

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I have the following unit test with chai, However even if I change the endpoint the unit test passes. I don't know how this is possible?

```
    var chai = require('chai');
    var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var server = require('./index.js');

    var should = chai.should();
    chai.use(chaiHttp);

    var agent = chai.request.agent(server.app);
    var Cookies;

    describe('integration tests for server component', function() {

      before(function (done) {
        //mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://someserver');
        chai.request(server.app)
           .post('/user/login')
           .send({email:'john@gmail.com'})
           .end(function(err, res){
             res.should.have.status(200);
             Cookies = res.headers['set-cookie'].pop().split(';')[0];
           });
        done();
      });
it('should GET /user/loggedin with status 200', function(done) {
    chai.request(server.app)
      .get('/user/loggedin')
      .end(function(err, res){
        res.should.have.status(200);
      });

    done();
  });

  it('should POST /user/isregistered with status 200', function(done) {
    var user = {
      email: 'John@gmail.com'
    };
    chai.request(server.app)
      .post('/user/isregistered')
      .send(user)
      .end(function(err, res){
        res.should.have.status(200);
      });
    done();
  });

  it('should GET /allskills', function(done){
    chai.request(server.app)
    .get('/user/allskills')
    .end(function(err, res){
      err.to.be.null;
      res.to.have.status(200);
      res.should.be.json;
      res.body[0].to.have.property('_id');
      res.body[0].to.have.property('name');
    });
    done();

  });
```

Is this the correct way to do unit tests with Chai?

The purpose of the before is to have a session in place. However I think I should create a session directly inside of it without making any call to `/user/login`

Comment: You need to call `done` inside the callback passed to `end`, otherwise you're prematurely telling Mocha that the test has completed.

Comment: oooooooooooooooohhhhhhh thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @robertklep pointed out, you should call `done()` within the callback given to `end()` after doing the expectations.

Because of the nature of the asynchronous request, `done()` was being called before the response came in. Make sure to always call `done()` immediately after the expectations in you make when the request is fulfilled.